# Using AngularJS dashboard templates

Tags: angularjs

How do you use those free AngularJS Dashboard Templates you find online?
I found many free angular dashboard templates.
They look nice, but I dont see documentation on how to use them,, some starting point for example.
Looks like you could use them to pull data from a database and represent it dynamically, but I dont know where to start in the most simplistic way.
for example, with this one:
http://startangular.com/product/flatlogic-angular-material-dashboard/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by merging your package.json and dev dependencies together, or using their project as the base, then you can do a lot in editing the partials in views/partials, and then for pulling data, you can implement an api into each of their controllers or pass information into each of the directives. There's no starting point for any data manipulation, it's more like a dashboard that you can send data into the panel-widget. This is only front-end stuff, so you must already have a location to pull data from.

Comment: Sounds very complicated,, if is this complicated then why they sell/publish templates for?. I would think there was some kind of documentation that says where to specify data sources, or fields, or some other parameters so the dashboard could read data from. A would imagine the word "template" means "usage with minimum work on the mechanics". Is there any easy way to feed the gauges on those templates with data from, lets say, a database in MySql without having to do much coding?

Comment: I don't think these packs are aimed towards beginners, but more programmers, who don't want to create UIs. Or most of these services purposely don't do that, so you pay their team to do it for you

Comment: I see,, yes,, that makes sense, It is unfortunately thought, I have a DB with data that gets populated realtime, with dashboards, and Im looking for a web management interface, that would let me read and sometimes push changes on the DB. I though an AngularJS template would allow me to do that. (the writing on the DB is not a priority,, but the "reading" and draw charts is.

Comment: Then one of these templates will work for you. You just need to understand Angular first, it follows the [angular seed design](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed), and there are lots of tutorials that teach you how directives and routing works. You also need to know how to make REST API calls in js, to inflate these views.

Comment: You gave me direction on this, and I appreciate it. Ill mark the question as answered, Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks a tonne, angular is a great framework and can be learned relatively quickly. Good luck!